# Bootstrap Multiple Select Dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-select

I am using a bootstrap-select, a JQuery multi-select plugin based on Bootstrap to create a multiple select dropdown.

I want to add some style to the dropdown, like changing the tick marks to checkboxes as in the image below

[image: Multiple select with Round checkboxes]

I don't know how to go about it. Anyone has an idea? I am open to another plugin if it's easier to customize.

Here is my code:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title='Choose one...' data-width=150px>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').selectpicker();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
.check-mark{
        color: whitesmoke;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding-left: 6.5px !important;
    }
    .bs-ok-default{
        background-color: black;
        width: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: yes thank you. But I also need an empty round checkbox to show next to the select item. How do I add it? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sorry I am not able to show an empty checkbox before it is checked, I can add one when it gets checked. Have a look at this [link](https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/).